# Put a shell script in the share menu?

Tags: finder

When I have a pdf open in various viewers (preview, foxit, skim), I often need to make a few edits by sending it to Affinity Designer.
However, this app isn't in the share menu, and seemingly can't be added by following the usual instructions.

How can I add any program to the share menu?

Comment: Have to tried using a Shortcut? Shortcuts are visible from the Share menu.

Comment: Use the "SHORTCUTS" app from Apple. I think preinstalled